# javascript multi-touch on win 7

Tags: javascript, windows-7, multi-touch

Is there any good solution for developing web applications that can work with iOS multitouch and Win 7 multitouch? Being limited to a specific browser such as firefox or chrome is acceptable but all of the browser combinations I have tried don't seem to work with any of the multitouch demo applications I have tried such as:

- [Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Touch_events) demo from mozilla
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/10/19/handling-multi-touch-and-mouse-input-in-all-browsers.aspx

[This](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/08/firefox4-beta3/) (very cool) demo of firefox multitouch does not seems to have an actual demo page that I can find and the Moz event functions used seem to be deprecated anyway according to the [Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Touch_events) page. Any pointers you can give will be very much appreciated.

Comment: i hate to say this, but - **sniff the browser..** Touch is not yet compatible across devices :(